# How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?

Tags: unix, find

In a terminal, how can I find files that are bigger or smaller than x bytes?

I suppose I can do something like

```
find . -exec ls -l {} \;
```

and then pipe the result to [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) to filter by file size. But shouldn't there be an easier way than this?

Answer (score 494, accepted):

Use:

```
find . -type f -size +4096c
```

to find files bigger than 4096 bytes.

And :

```
find . -type f -size -4096c
```

to find files smaller than 4096 bytes.

Notice the + and - difference after the size switch.

The `-size` switch explained:

```
-size n[cwbkMG]

    File uses n units of space. The following suffixes can be used:

    `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix  is
                                used)

    `c'    for bytes

    `w'    for two-byte words

    `k'    for Kilobytes       (units of 1024 bytes)

    `M'    for Megabytes    (units of 1048576 bytes)

    `G'    for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)

    The size does not count indirect blocks, but it does count
    blocks in sparse files that are not actually allocated. Bear in
    mind that the `%k' and `%b' format specifiers of -printf handle
    sparse files differently. The `b' suffix always denotes
    512-byte blocks and never 1 Kilobyte blocks, which is different
    to the behaviour of -ls.
```

Comment: @Jay: From [man find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) at the beginning of the "Tests" section: "Numeric arguments can be specified as +n for greater than n, -n for less than n, n for exactly n."

Comment: The man page mentions it towards the top and describes that + and - can apply to all switches that take numeric ('n') arguments, including what + and - mean.  (Search for TESTS in the man page to find the beginning of the section where this is described)

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: weird, + and - work in OS X, but the man page doesn't have the TESTS section. In fact, it is missing a big chunk compared to your link, it's missing TESTs, ACTIONS, OPERATORS, among others.

Comment: It appears the GNU version of the man page has the "Tests" section, but the BSD version does not. http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php

Comment: The solaris man page has an "Expression" section that explains it too. http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-0210/6m6nb7m9j?l=en&a=view

Comment: I just found out the BSD man pages do describe the +/- thing. Its way at the end of the "Primaries" section. -- All primaries which take a numeric argument allow the number to be preceded by a plus sign ( “+” ) or a minus sign ( “-” ) . A preceding plus sign means “more than n”, a preceding minus sign means “less than n” and neither means “exactly n”

Comment: This is a legitimate documentation bug - the only use case you would generally want for find is *+n* or *-n* ; never an exact size. OP can you raise a documentation bug?

Comment: I don't know why the cat wanted all files smaller or bigger. But isn't ‛find -type f -not -size 4096c‛ easier then?

Comment: What if a file exactly 4096byte? Than which line will be executing it?

Comment: How about bigger than 100k, less then 1M in one command?

Comment: **find -size -1k** will not find files smaller than 1k... (bug?), but -2k works as expected.  **-1024c** also works correctly.

Comment: I could not get any "less than" variant to work on Ubuntu, but a `-not` "more than" variant did.

Comment: TRIG is right the less than variant fails on Ubuntu but using `-not` works, e.g. `find . -type f -size +2G -not -size +3G` finds files between 2GB and 3GB.

Comment: Regarding `find -size -1k`, you should use `find -size -1024c` instead, if you are using find 4.8.0 (GNU findutils): “The + and - prefixes signify greater than and less than, as usual; i.e., an exact size of `n` units does not match.  Bear in mind that the size is rounded up to the next unit. Therefore `-size -1M` is not equivalent to `-size -1048576c`.  The former only matches empty files, the latter matches files from 0 to 1,048,575 bytes.”

Answer (score 15):

I think `find` might be useful alone without piping to AWK. For example,

```
find ~ -type f -size +2k  -exec ls -sh {} \;
```

The tilde indicates where you want your search to begin and the result should display only files greater than 2 kilobytes.

To make it fancy, you can use the `-exec` option to execute another command which is to list these directories with their sizes.

For more information, read up the [man page for `find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

Answer (score 7):

AWK really is quite easy for this sort of thing. Here are some things you can do with it in relation to file size checking, like you asked:

List files greater than 200 bytes:

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($5 > 200) print $8}'
```

List files less than 200 bytes and write the list to a file:

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($5 < 200) print $8}' | tee -a filelog
```

List files of 0 bytes, record the list to a file and delete the empty files:

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($5 == 0) print $8}' | tee -a deletelog | xargs rm
```

Comment: [parsing `ls` is not good](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: What is the difference between piping to `tee` and just redirecting to a file, like `ls -l > filelog` (or `ls -l >> filelog`)?

Answer (score 5):

Greater than 2000 bytes:

```
du -a . | awk '$1*512 > 2000 {print $2}'
```

Less than 2000 bytes:

```
du -a . | awk '$1*512 < 2000 {print $2} '
```

Comment: This is bad as du gives the space on the disk occupied. This is not the same as a file size. eg if you have a compressed file system (btrfs/zfs) du will give you a different result from ls which shows the actual decompressed size.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), which is much nicer to use than `find`

```
fd -S +1g
```

will search under the current directory for any files larger than 1GB

```
fd -S -1g
```

will search for files *smaller* than 1GB