# List files bigger than filesize specified

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

How can I make ls (or any other command) list only files bigger than a specific file size?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) and its `-size` flag.

To find files larger than 100MB:

```
find . -type f -size +100M
```

If you want the current dir only:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +100M
```

Comment: If you need to pass the size in bytes, use `find . -type f -size +4096c
` (https://superuser.com/a/204571/111289)

Comment: just to extend the answer:
to get the number of files bigger than specified, pipe it to word count `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +100M  | wc`

Answer (score 42):

If you wish to see all files over 100M and to see where they are and what is their size try this:

```
find . -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to use printf parameter `-printf "%p %s"`. See: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Comment: @Nux: nice tip.  `-printf '%9s %p\n'` worked well for me.

Comment: Building on this answer:  `find /var/lib/docker/containers -name "*-json.log" -type f -size +100M -exec /bin/cp -f /dev/null {} \;`

Comment: @Nux The problem with using `%s` is that while the size it prints is machine parsable, it's not human-readable, whereas `ls -lh` shows a human readable size.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
find / -size gt 2MB
```

or:

```
find / -size => 2000000
```

Comment: How does this improve the accepted answer?

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: Alternative syntax is sometimes useful and insightful. +1